# lsyncd - OVERFLOW in event queue - Solution is to tune fs.inotify.max_queued_events

Tags: linux, rsync, inotify, sysctl, lsyncd

lsyncd is a fantastic alternative to NFS or NAS for replicating files among your Linux hosts.  I have found the daemon works well with large Linux filesystems (many files, small to large sizes, xfs, ext4, luks) but requires some sysctl tuning as your filesystem grows.

This "question" is a note to myself so I can always find the answer via searching on stack overflow. Hope it helps you!

Github Project: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd

#### Exception in /var/log/lsyncd.log:

```
Thu Jun 18 17:48:52 2020 Normal: --- OVERFLOW in event queue ---
Thu Jun 18 17:48:52 2020 Normal: --- HUP signal, resetting ---
Thu Jun 18 17:48:52 2020 Normal: waiting for 1 more child processes.
```

Comment: Ha! So, I'm not the only nerd that uses SO this way... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution when you see "OVERFLOW in event queue" in lsyncd.log

From other knowledge bases, I had learned to tune **max_user_watches**, but by also tuning the **max_queued_events**, I corrected an OVERFLOW in event queue exception.

The temporary solution worked without needing to restart my lsyncd process.

I picked the number 1000000 as an arbitrarily large number.  The default Ubuntu 18 value is 16384.

#### Temporary Solution

Check your current tuning values:

```sh
$ sysctl fs.inotify.max_queued_events
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 16384
$ sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 8192
```

Update both max_user_watches and max_queued_events via shell

```sh
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1000000
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_queued_events=1000000
```

#### Permanent Solution, Persists after reboot

Update both max_user_watches and max_queued_events in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1000000
fs.inotify.max_queued_events=1000000
```

#### Lsyncd.conf Basic Configuration

/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf

```
settings {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd.log",
    pidfile = "/var/run/lsyncd/lsyncd.pid",
    insist = true
}
sync {
   default.rsyncssh,
   source="/var/application/data",
   host="node2",
   excludeFrom="/etc/lsyncd/exclude",
   targetdir="/var/application/data",
   rsync = {
     archive = true,
     compress = false,
     whole_file = true
   },
   ssh = {
     port = 22
   }
}
```

#### System Details

Linux service1staging 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

lsyncd --version
Version: 2.1.6